# Proving that a quadratic equation has no integer solution if c=2n and n is odd

Tags: solution-verification, quadratics

My textbook makes the proposition: For all integers $m$ and $n$,  if $n$ is odd, then the equation \begin{align}
x^2+2mx+2n=0
\end{align}
Has no integer solution for $x$.

It asks me to prove via a proof by contradiction. I assumed the negation of the proposition is: There exists integers $m$ and $n$, where $n$ is odd and the equation $x^2+2mx+2n=0$ has an integer solution for $x$.

If $n$ is odd there must be some integer $a$ such that $n=2a+1$. Substituting that we get $$x^2+2mx+2(2a+1)=0\\x^2+2mx+4a+2=0$$ If we put that into a quadratic equation, we get $$\frac{-2m \pm \sqrt{(2m)^2-4(1)(4a+2)}}{2(1)} = \frac{-2m \pm \sqrt{4m^2-16a-8}}{2} = \frac{-2m \pm \sqrt{4(m^2-4a-2)}}{2} = \frac{-2m \pm 2 \sqrt{m^2-4a-2}}{2} = -m \pm \sqrt{m^2-4a-2}$$ So the way I see to find a contradiction is for that to not possibly be an integer, or for $m$ or $a$ to also not be integers or something. But I am lost trying to find the contradiction. If someone can please help.

Comment: Alt. hint: if one of the roots is an integer, then so is the other one. Their sum is even, so they have the same parity, and their product cannot be an even number that is not also a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution can be finished by noting that every integer square must be congruent to $0$ or $1$ (mod $4$) (that is, is of the form $4j$ or $4j+1$), which forces $m^2-4a-2$ to be congruent to $2$ or $3$ (mod $4$) and thus cannot be a perfect square.

Alternatively, we can look at the original expression $x^2+2mx+2n$ and note that:

- if $x$ is odd, then $x^2+2(mx+n)$ is odd and hence not equal to $0$;
- if $x$ is even, then $x^2+2mx$ is a multiple of $4$, and hence $x^2+2mx+2n$ is congruent to $2$ (mod $4$) and thus still not equal to $0$.

Comment: +1....We can also say that if $x$ is even and if $x^2+2mx+2n=0$ then $n=-2((x/2)^2+m(x/2))$ is even.